# bs4 returns [] when i'm trying to scrape details from website

Tags: python

i'm still a bit new to this python stuff but i'm pretty sure i selected the right class

i'm basically trying to get the floor count on the website but it always returns []

how would i go about this? i did realize there were other stat-titles but i also tried it with a selector and it still returned []

```html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="https://www.jpg.store/collection/cardano4speed"


html_content = requests.get(url).text


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
print(soup.select('.stat-title'))
```

Comment: I have Javascript turned off in my browser and I see no elements on that page with the CSS class `stat-title`. If it's a dynamically generated page, you'll need something more heavy-duty that BeautifulSoup to scrape it. Selenium comes to mind.

Comment: Is there any other way than Selenium? I've also tried Puppeteer but still nothing.

Comment: I haven't used puppeteer personally, but at a glance it looks similar to Selenium in that it emulates a human agent browsing. Either should work for your use case

Comment: The problem is that I want to avoid using those headless browser stuff though. Would there be any other way of scraping from a dynamically generated page other than those options?

Comment: You need something that can run Javascript, and that thing is called a headless browser. Just querying the page and scanning XML doesn't work if the page only exists *after* the script is run

Comment: Thanks! Had it work with Selenium and it works fine.